# Reduce Margin on a Square layout (Android)

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have the following layout, that is inside a SquareGridViewItem that extends LinearLayout to create a Square layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="top">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square_grid_view.image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/oitavoano_icon"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/square_grid_view.text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#D0E4F3"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            fontPath="fonts/Brother1816Book.ttf"
            android:text="8ª série A"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/square_grid_view.top_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#A4BED2"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/square_grid_view.left_divider"
        android:layout_width="0.5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#A4BED2"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/square_grid_view.right_divider"
        android:layout_width="0.5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#A4BED2"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Everthing works fine, but I need to lower all margins of the inside elements so they will be closer to all 4 borders, how can I do that?

This is how the layout looks like now.

[image]

I need to lower every margin, and still looks centered.
Or at least the bottom margin.

Comment: Could you post the preview of this layout?

Comment: Who is the parent of `SquareGridViewItem`? Where is this view inflated at?

Comment: SquareGridViewItem is the root view of the layout, there's nothing above it. I just couldnt post it's code. But it's a wrap_content both in height and width and extends LinearLayout and overrides  the onMeasure method

 public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec , widthMeasureSpec  );
    }